# Filling in Wikipedia's articles about Talmud

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to post to organize Mi Yodeya users, but I figured this would just get merged/closed if this isn't the correct place.

It turns out that Wikipedia's articles about individual tractates of Mishna / Gemarra are quite weak.  In many cases, especially tractates of Mishnah that don't have any Gemarra at all (all of Kodashim, most of Toharot) there aren't even articles at all, and instead they link to the seder that they fall into (so if you type in "keritot" it just re-directs you to "kodashim").

I was thinking that since the Mi Yodeya community obviously knows quite a bit about this topic, we could organize to fill out those articles.  Does this seem like a good idea? As a relatively experienced Wikipedian, I would be willing to help out with Wikipedia-related issues. I'm just asking here because I don't personally have a lot to add to those pages, though I know some members of the community do.

Also, how can we get the word out to the regular users of Mi Yodeya who do not normally check meta?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6603/5

Comment: Similar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:School_and_university_projects